# How to sort a doubly linked list with the nodes instead of the node's values

Tags: c++, class, sorting, doubly-linked-list, insertion-sort

I am trying to sort a doubly linked list with the nodes for an assignment because thats what the spec wants me to do. I thought to basically make a new list with the sorted and then assign the head and tail

The two .h files of my program:

```
#ifndef SN_H
#define SN_H

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

//SortNode class implementation here
template <class T>
class SortNode
{
    protected:
        T value;
    public:
        SortNode<T> * next;
        SortNode<T> * prev;
        SortNode(T);
        std :: string print();
        T getValue();
};

#include "SortNode.cpp"

#endif
```

```
#ifndef DLL_H
#define DLL_H

#include "SortNode.h"

template <class T>
class SortList 
{
    private:
        bool ascending;
        SortNode<T> * head;
        SortNode<T> * tail;

    public:
        SortList(bool);
        void add(SortNode<T>* a) ;
        SortNode<T>* remove(T val);  
        void setAsc(bool a);
        void sort() ;
        string print() ;
        SortNode<T>*getHead() ;
        string debug() ;

};


#include "SortList.cpp"

#endif
```

I have tried to sort it like i described but then it gets stuck in a loop and don't have an idea how to do this.

This is the sort function that gives me problems.

```
template <class T>
void SortList<T> :: sort()
{

cout<<"above if "<<endl;
    if (ascending == true)
    {
        SortNode<T> * node = head, *ptr = NULL ,*sortedh = NULL, *sortedt = NULL, *newnode = NULL;
        
        while (node != NULL)
        {
            newnode = node;
           
            if (!sortedh)
            {
                sortedh = node;
                sortedt = node;
            }
            else
            {
               
                ptr = head;

                while (ptr!= NULL && ptr -> getValue() < newnode -> getValue())
                {
                    ptr = ptr -> next;
                }

                if (!ptr)
                {
                    sortedt -> next = newnode;
                    newnode ->prev = sortedt;
                    sortedt = newnode;

                }
                else
                {
                    if (ptr ->prev == NULL)
                    {
                        newnode -> next = ptr;
                        ptr -> prev =newnode;
                        sortedh = newnode;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ptr -> prev -> next = newnode;
                        newnode -> prev =ptr -> prev;
                        newnode -> next =ptr;
                        ptr -> prev = newnode;
                    }
                    
                }


            }
            
            
            node = node -> next;
        }

      
    }
  
    

}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: believe me, in real life  you will never need to sort a linked list. if this is a requirement, you have chosen the wrong data structure. i can't remember ever using a linked list professionally. but if you must sort the values, traverse the list, read them into a vector and sort that. this exercise is bogus.

Comment: You will have to leave the nodes in their memory locations and be creative with their links. Try drawing a toy doubly linked list on paper, and start rearanging the pointers. Now try to duplicate that in code. Hint new head will point to node with smallest value (assuming ascending sort order). Making a new list will not be needed, this is one of the (few) benefits of double linked lists (with relative large data in the nodes, not much memory needs to be changed).

Comment: @NeilButterworth I know in real life no one will use linked lists like this but this is for marks and I have to do it even if it's as dumb as we both know it is. Unfortunately, I only have access to the libraries in the .h files.

Comment: @NeilButterworth While that can be true in practice, it is not the OP's assignment. And the best data structure still depends on a lot of data properties. And while rare there are situations where lists can outperform vectors. (Sorting a vector involves moving data for each element.

Comment: Lists (and other node-based containers) have one important benefit - they have stable iterators. Performance is not always (or maybe, almost always is not) the primary factor and sometimes stable iterators can simplify code considerably.

Comment: Wow, those header guard names are short and potentially problematic.

Comment: @Pep sorting typically requires random access, which lists don't provide - i would stuff things in a vector, sort it, then stuff them into a new list, which is then moved to the old list

Comment: @PepijnKramer Please show a real-life example where sorting a linked list is actually faster than sorting a `std::vector`. Even if it has to reallocate and copy elements, I will bet real money that it'll still be faster than all the pointer chasing and cache misses of the list - in real life situations.

Comment: @NeilButterworth and Jasper I see your point now, it is having to follow the links linearly (even doubly linked list) that is indeed not likely to be faster (that linear search must be offset by large memory copies to be worth it0.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: I may be in the minority, but I think that this is a good and important exercise. The point of it is not to learn how to get a list sorted, but to learn how sorting works and how dynamic structures can be rearranged. Yes, in real life I would use copy it into a `std::list` and `sort()` that, but I see a lot of questions from beginners who get in trouble because they don't understand how sorting and pointers work.

Comment: @Beta are you some sort of linked list fanboy? lists are not intended to be sortable. and if you want an exercise with pointers and dynamically allocated memory, sort a vector of pointers into a list. linked lists should always be the last data structure you reach for.

Comment: @NeilButterworth: Were you bitten by a linked list as a child? Without a basic understanding of sorting, one can't even understand what people in this thread are talking about, and a coder who does only trivial exercises with pointers will be in trouble when the time comes to deal with directed graphs.

Comment: @Beta my opinions on linked lists come from me teaching C programming at a training company where the C course main feature was a linked list. i didn't write the course, but i always thought it silly. C++ course which i co-wrote just used dynamically allocated arrays (all pre srd kib)

Comment: @NeilButterworth *lists are not intended to be sortable* - This makes no sense. There are algorithms that naturally sort lists.

Comment: @Evg of  course there are - there are for any container, but if one of the things i needed was sorting, i would never choose a linked list. and for a lot of other reasons.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Never? This sounds way too strong. I'm pretty sure we'll be able to find good practical examples of linked list sorting over the whole industry. The fact we don't know them says more about our own ignorance...

Comment: @Evg ok. go for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code has bugs.

For example in this code snippet there are even two bugs.

```
        if (!sortedh)
        {
            sortedh = node;
            sortedt = node;
        }
        else
        {
           
            ptr = head;
            //...
```

Instead you need to write

```
        if (!sortedh)
        {
            sortedh = node;
            sortedt = node;
            node->next = nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
           
            ptr = sortedh;
            //...
```

Or in this if statement

```
if (!ptr)
{
    sortedt -> next = newnode;
    newnode ->prev = sortedt;
    sortedt = newnode;
}
```

you forgot to set the data member next of the node pointed to by the pointer `newnode` like

```
if (!ptr)
{
    sortedt -> next = newnode;
    newnode ->prev = sortedt;
    newnode->next = nullptr; 
    sortedt = newnode;
}
```

Or in this if statement

```
if (ptr ->prev == NULL)
{
    newnode -> next = ptr;
    ptr -> prev =newnode;
    sortedh = newnode;
}
```

you forgot to set the data member prev of the node pointed to by the pointer newnode as for example

```
newnode -> next = ptr;
newnode->prev = ptr->prev; or newnode->prev = nullptr;
```

And there is one more problem. The data member next of the node pointed to by the pointer `node` can be changed. So this statement

```
node = node -> next;
```

can result in that the pointer `node` can point to an already processed node.

Also the function does not set the pointers `head` and `tail`.

Here is a demonstration program that shows how the function that implements the insertion sort method can be defined. To simplify writing the program I have made some minor changes in the class definitions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

//SortNode class implementation here
template <class T>
class SortNode
{
protected:
    T value;
public:
    SortNode *prev;
    SortNode *next;

    SortNode( const T &value, SortNode *prev = nullptr, SortNode *next = nullptr )
    {
        this->value = value;
        this->prev  = prev;
        this->next  = next;
    }

    const T & getValue() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    T & getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
};

template <class T>
class SortList
{
private:
    bool ascending = true;
    SortNode<T> *head = nullptr;
    SortNode<T> *tail = nullptr;

public:
    SortList() = default;
    void add( const T &value )
    {
        SortNode<T> *new_node = new SortNode<T>{ value, tail, nullptr };

        if (!head)
        {
            head = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = new_node;
        }

        tail = new_node;
    }

    SortNode<T> *remove( T val );
    void setAsc( bool a );
    void sort();
    std::ostream &print( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const
    {
        for (SortNode<T> *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next)
        {
            os << current->getValue() << " -> ";
        }

        return os << "null";
    }
    SortNode<T> *getHead();
};

template <class T>
void SortList<T> ::sort()
{
    if (ascending)
    {
        SortNode<T> *node = head, *sortedh = nullptr, *sortedt = nullptr;

        while (node != NULL)
        {
            SortNode<T> *newnode = node;
            SortNode<T> *next = node->next;

            if (!sortedh)
            {
                sortedh = node;
                sortedt = node;
                node->next = nullptr;
            }
            else
            {
                SortNode<T> *ptr = sortedh;

                while (ptr != NULL && !( newnode->getValue() < ptr->getValue() ) )
                {
                    ptr = ptr->next;
                }

                if (!ptr)
                {
                    sortedt->next = newnode;
                    newnode->prev = sortedt;
                    newnode->next = nullptr;
                    sortedt = newnode;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (ptr->prev == NULL)
                    {
                        newnode->next = ptr;
                        newnode->prev = nullptr;
                        ptr->prev = newnode;
                        sortedh = newnode;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ptr->prev->next = newnode;
                        newnode->prev = ptr->prev;
                        newnode->next = ptr;
                        ptr->prev = newnode;
                    }

                }
            }

            node = next;
        }

        head = sortedh;
        tail = sortedt;
    }
}

int main()
{
    SortList<int> list;

    const int N = 20;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( nullptr ) );
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        list.add( rand() % N );
    }

    list.print() << '\n';

    list.sort();

    list.print() << '\n';
}
```

The program output might look like

```
17 -> 12 -> 0 -> 12 -> 8 -> 8 -> 8 -> 13 -> 4 -> 7 -> 8 -> 11 -> 7 -> 8 -> 18 -> 4 -> 16 -> 18 -> 18 -> 3 -> null
0 -> 3 -> 4 -> 4 -> 7 -> 7 -> 8 -> 8 -> 8 -> 8 -> 8 -> 11 -> 12 -> 12 -> 13 -> 16 -> 17 -> 18 -> 18 -> 18 -> null
```

Comment: The funny thing about this, it was the code I got from the lecture slides that were given to me.

Comment: @DVW It seems the lecturer is a professional programmer. So we as beginners have to rewrite the code after such professional programmers.:)

Comment: Thank you are an absolute legend for this!!